# Docker build failure due to “mount volume over existing file”

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I am running into an issue where my builds are failing because of the following error:

`Step 12/13 : VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/a3d9ab74930d907691fb8870a29ea08b8fab0bd0fd7ecb1064982be512d904fa/var/lib/postgresql/data`

I built the image earlier, ran it locally (without mounting the volume), then edited the Dockerfile, and attempted to build it again. I’ve removed all of my stopped containers, as well as deleted all of my dangling volumes. `docker volume ls` shows no volumes, yet I am still getting this error. Additionally, each time I run it the directory name after mnt changes in the error message.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM multiarch/alpine:armhf-v3.7
ENV GOSU_DOWNLOAD_KEY="0x036A9C25BF357DD4"

ENV PGDATA /var/lib/postgresql/data

ADD pg_hba.conf /var/lib/postgresql/data
ADD postgresql.conf /var/lib/postgresql/data
ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /

RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql tzdata curl gnupg && \
    gpg-agent --daemon && \
    gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys $GOSU_DOWNLOAD_KEY && \
    echo "trusted-key $GOSU_DOWNLOAD_KEY" >> /root/.gnupg/gpg.conf && \
    curl -sSL https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.10/gosu-armhf > gosu && \
    curl -sSL https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.10/gosu-armhf.asc > gosu.asc && \
    gpg --verify gosu.asc && \
    rm gosu.asc && \
    mv gosu /usr/bin/gosu && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/gosu && \
    apk del --purge curl gnupg && \
    rm -rf /root.gnupg

ENTRYPOINT /docker-entrypoint.sh
EXPOSE 5432

VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data

CMD "postgres"
```

Why are these builds failing? I'm using docker for mac.

Comment: could you show how you pass `-v` env variable. .in docker-compose file if you use docker-compose or the way you issue `docker run` if you run build manually. .

Comment: I am not using docker-compose for this. Here's how I ran docker run: `docker run --rm -it postgres /bin/sh`, ran a few postgres operations to test the image, then exited out of the image.

Comment: Additionally, I ran `docker system prune -a` and attempted to build it again. I received the same error.

Comment: Are you able to post the Dockerfile?

Comment: @TillHoffmann edited this post with the Dockerfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You copy the postgres configuration using `ADD postgresql.conf /var/lib/postgresql/data` which has the same path as the volume you are trying to mount using `VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data`, which is not allowed to prevent unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't accurate.

when it comes to Dockerfile and ADD/COPY commands and VOLUME it doesn't matter which order they are in.

In a dockerfile the VOLUME command ensures that the resulting image doesn't have data in the specified path during the build or later docker commit commands on running containers.  In fact each running container has a separate volume created for that path.  EXCEPT for ADD and COPY commands.  Those commands will ALWAYS produce data in the specified path in the resulting docker image.

This error is likely because the FROM docker image already contains a VOLUME declaration in the same path.